# How to make this stored procedure use a JSON check?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2017

I am looking at using a stored procedure to help out with a situation of where I have to update/insert about a 1000 records. I was given the suggestion to use `MERGE` with a table-valued parameter to achieve this but the problem is one of the columns is a JSON string.

**ItemsTbl**

```
id -PK
BrandId- int (FK)
LocationId- int (FK)
Field3 - nvarchar(Max) Json string containing a jsonKey called itemNumber


select * 
from ItemsTbl 
where BrandId = 1 
  and LocationId = 1 
  and JSON_VALUE('Field3',$.itemNumber) = 12345
```

Now the stored procedure (what is pretty much all new to me) looks currently like this:

```
/* Create a table type. */  
CREATE TYPE SourceTableType AS TABLE   
( BrandId INT  
, LocationId INT
, ItemNumber INT
, ...
);  
GO 

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_InsertTvp  
    @Source SourceTableType READONLY  
AS        
    MERGE INTO Table1 AS Target  
    USING @Source As Source ON Target.BrandId = Source.BrandId 
                            AND Target.LocationId = Source.LocationId 
                            AND Target.ItemNumber = Source.ItemNumber  

    WHEN MATCHED THEN  
        UPDATE SET OtherParam = Source.OtherParam  

    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
        INSERT (BrandId, LocationId, ItemNumber, OtherParam) 
        VALUES (BrandId, LocationId, ItemNumber, OtherParam) ;
```

The problem is this right now does not seem to account on that `ItemNumber` is inside a JSON string and not it's own column. So I don't think this would work

```
 Target.ItemNumber = Source.ItemNumber
```

Also I am guessing `SourceTableType` would have to take in `Field3` as a parameter and then extract it out itself?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you right.
Please try this:

```
;WITH MergeTarget AS (
    SELECT t.BrandId,t.LocationId,t.Field3,JSON_VALUE(t.Field3,'$.itemNumber') AS [ItemNumber],t.OtherParam
    FROM Table1 AS t
)
MERGE MergeTarget AS target
USING (
    SELECT s.BrandId,s.LocationId,s.ItemNumber,'{"itemNumber":"'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255),s.ItemNumber)+'"' AS [Field3],s.OtherParam
    FROM @Source AS s
) AS source ON source.BrandId = target.BrandId
    AND source.LocationId = target.LocationId
    AND source.ItemNumber = target.ItemNumber
WHEN MATCHED AND target.OtherParam <> source.OtherParam THEN UPDATE SET target.OtherParam = source.OtherParam
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (BrandId, LocationId, Field3, OtherParam) 
    VALUES(source.BrandId,source.LocationId,source.Field3,source.OtherParam)
;
```

Any questions also please let me know.